# Canvas.scale output renders not always the same

Tags: macos, python-3.x, animation, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I do a first simple tkinter tool. It connects via FTP to a server and uploads a file (it's for a restaurant's menucard to go on their server).
All this is working fine. 
I'm trying to make an animation indicating the upload. And there is a problem.

- The main-class inherits from Tk
- inits menu, buttons and such, relevant: `self.anim = Canvas(self, width=500, height=300)  # Canvas for Animation
      self.anim.grid(column=0, row=5)`
- eventually, when uploading it calls `self.animation()`
- There I draw a little PC via `create_...` methods and then what should be the card, zooming out the screen and going up. Running I see like maybe 4 of 5 runs how it is supposed to show up (so far) but sometimes it looks like it renders that animations two times (second double in factor) and these are overlapping, zooming twice as big and going far out of intended stop...
  That's not a good sign, same input, different output. Anyone can explain why this happens?

  ```
  x0, y0, x1, y1 = (185, 100, 190, 110)   # menucard
  ix0, iy0, ix1, iy1 = (187, 102, 189, 104)  # menucard's "image"
  self.speisekarte = self.anim.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1,   # menucard
                                                outline='#bbb', fill='#fef',
                                                stipple='gray75', tag='karte')
  self.karteimg = self.anim.create_rectangle(ix0, iy0, ix1, iy1,  # menucard's "image"
                                             outline='#f77', fill='#f57',
                                             stipple='gray50', tag='karte')
  self.anim.create_line(185, 100, 185, 109, tag='karte')
  self.anim.update()

  for z in range(13):
      self.anim.after(100, self.zoom())

  for z in range(50):
      self.anim.after(50, self.move())


  self.anim.create_text(350, 50, text='O N L I N E !', fill='#f57')
  ```

  `def zoom(self):
     self.anim.scale('karte', 185, 110, 1.09, 1.06)
     self.anim.update()`

  `def move(self):
      self.anim.move('karte', 2, -1)
      self.anim.update()`

Comment: `after` needs function name - it means without `()`

Comment: you're right, that seemed an issue! Now it's fast as hell. So, the execution outside the called function won't wait for it? It's always finished with `create_text` at the end long before the zoom/move are.

Comment: you use the same time in all `after()` so all `zoom()` are executed at the same time. You need `after(100,...)`, `after(200, ...)`, etc. or you could use `after()` inside `zoom()`  like in [clock example](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/tkinter/timer-using-after/clock-function.py) in function `update_time()`

Answer (score 0):

@furas helped me to my solution. From there I had to find a way to exit the function. I found nowwhere an example, so here how it works for me now:

`def animdrawUpload(self):
    while self.move():
        pass
    return True`

```
def move(self):
    if self.anim.coords('karte')[0] > 300:
        return False
    self.anim.move('karte', 2, -1)
    self.anim.update()
    self.anim.after(100, self.move)
    return True
```

Eventually I just have to hope I will get the same result on windows10  ;)

Comment: You don't need the `self.anim.update()`, if that's the built-in `update` method. I'm also not sure why you need `while self.move()` -- you should call `move` exactly once, and it will run for the life of your program.

Comment: On OS X it worked the way intended. That way I could controll every step of the animation and sync it with the upload status..(ftp functions connects=animation zooms, ftp uploads=animation moves, ftp succed=animation shows success). Windows, wherere I'm on now, renders it with no pause, way to fast. I changed how you suggested it. With `self.after_cancel(self.move)` to exit. Throws index errors now. For real I only find examples of animations reacting to user inputs. It shouldn't run for the life of my programm, it should animate until a given position and then return True.